# Should I repartition dataframe on a column before groupBy?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Dataframe df1 contains 10 million rows. Column PID contains 256 unique values.
In pyspark, I plan to execute the following query just once.

```
df1.createTempView("df1")
spark.sql(""" SELECT PID, count(*) as Count
              FROM df1
              GROUP BY PID""")
```

Will the execution be faster if I first repartition on column PID? 
I was told that it will, but based on my understanding, as the query has to be executed only once, it will not.
Repartitioning on PID **before** execution will cause data shuffling, so will `group by` without repartitioning.